# Apply HTML elements dynamically from JS in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have an html element:
`<span style="font-size: smaller;font-weight: 400;white-space: initial;text-transform: none;">`
I want to dynamically apply this html element to an Accordion Section label, on Page load , from JS file.

Is there a way to dynamically apply HTML tags from JS? When I tried, it is printing this element in the form of text.

Any help?

Comment: Based on the info you've given, it's not clear why you want to dynamically add an HTML tag via JavaScript, vs. using `<template if:true|false={myBoolean}>` ([see docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_conditional)) or simply hard-coding the accordion label.  If you really need to manipulate the DOM with JavaScript, please see [these docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) and let us know if you got what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Modifications to the internal details of a component is not allowed in LWC

Salesforce Support